# How dont flush the persisted entity in Symfony2 with Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="showpage", requirements={"id" : "\d+"})
 */
public function showAction(Car $car, Request $request)
{
    // I have fetched $car
    $form = $this->createForm(CarType::class, $car);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $driver = new Driver();
        // Some logic...
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($driver);
        $em->flush();
        //...
    }
    //..
 }
```

I want only get info and form by `$car`, but dont want update it.
How can I block `flush()` for my `$car`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or flush only `$driver`.

```
$em->flush($driver);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to detach the entity. You can do that with

```
$em->detach($car);
```

Comment: I tried, but then I have problem with relationship (one car has many drivers) and cannt resolve it.